# Banach algebra structure of $\ell^p$ sequence space

Tags: banach-spaces, lp-spaces, maximal-and-prime-ideals, banach-algebras, absolute-convergence

**Long intro: questions after examples.**

[The space of absolutely convergent sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_sequence_space_%E2%84%93p) $\ell^1 = \{ \vec{a} = (a_1, a_2, a_3, ...) \in \Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}: \sum_{n} |a_n| < \infty \}$ is closed under vector multiplication and scalar addition, and has a natural norm (though not inner product) given by $|| \vec{a} || = \sum_n |a_n|$. While this space is typically considered as a [complete normed vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space), I'm curious about its structure as a commutative ring endowed with various types of permutation-invariant multiplication. A multiplication $\otimes$ will be *permutation invariant* if for every permutation $\sigma: \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$, we have $$||(|a_{\sigma(n)}|) \otimes (|b_{\sigma(n)}|)|| = ||(|a_n|) \otimes (|b_n|)||.$$

There are three "natural"-seeming, permutation-invariant multiplications to define, which are each [continuous with respect to the norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra):

- $\underline{\text{Componentwise.}}$ $\ell^1$ is closed under componentwise multiplication: if $( a_n ), ( b_n ) \in \ell^1$, then the componentwise product $$( a_n ) \cdot ( b_n ) := ( a_n b_n ) \in \ell^1,$$ and $||\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}|| \leq ||\vec{a}|| ||\vec{b}||$, so this makes $\ell^1$ into a Banach algebra. Every ideal is generated by one or more ideals of the form $$\mathfrak{a}_I = \{ (a_n) \in \ell^1 : a_k = 0, \forall k \in I \},$$ for some (possibly empty) index set $I \subseteq \Bbb{N}$. The ideal $\mathfrak{a}_I$ is all of $\ell^1$ only if $I = \emptyset$ and a prime or maximal ideal only if $I = \{ k \}$ is a single element.
- $\underline{\text{Cauchy product.}}$ Since [the Cauchy product of two absolutely convergent sequences is absolutely convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/326532/), $\ell_1$ is closed under Cauchy products: $$( a_n ) * ( b_n ) := ( c_n ) \in \ell^1,$$ where $c_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k b_{n-k+1}$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ and it only takes a little algebra (omitted) to show that $|| \vec{a} * \vec{b} || \leq ||\vec{a}|| ||\vec{b}||$. So this is a Banach algebra again, and because elements of $\ell^1$ are in 1-1 correspondence with power series $\sum_n a_n x^{n-1}$ that converge absolutely on the closed interval $[-1, 1]$, the maximal ideals of $\ell^1$ are in 1-1 correspondence with points $x \in [-1, 1]$ via the correspondence $$x \mapsto \mathfrak{m}_x := \{ (a_n): \sum_{n} a_n x^{n-1} = 0 \}.$$ Every other ideal is an intersection of some (finite number of) the $\mathfrak{m}_x$, a power of one of the $\mathfrak{m}_x$, or a combination of the two.
- $\underline{\text{Dirichlet convolution.}}$ For two elements $(a_n), (b_n) \in \ell^1$, the Dirichlet convolution of these sequences is also in $\ell^1:$ $$(a_n) \star (b_n) = (d_n) \in \ell^1 ,$$ where $d_n = \sum_{k | n} a_k b_{n/k}$. We can show that $(d_n) \in \ell^1$ similarly to showing that the Cauchy product converges:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N |d_n| &= \sum_{n=1}^N \left| \sum_{k | n} a_k b_{n/k} \right| \\
 &\leq \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k | N} |a_k| |b_{n/k}| \\
 &= \sum_{\substack{1 \leq j, k \leq N \\ jk \leq N}} |a_j| |b_k| \\
 &\leq \sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^N |a_j| |b_k| \\
 &= \left(\sum_{j=1}^N |a_j|\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^N |b_k|\right), \
\end{align*}

and by letting $N \to \infty$ we see that $||\vec{d}|| = ||\vec{a} \star \vec{b}||$ is finite, and $||\vec{a} \star \vec{b}|| \leq ||\vec{a}|| ||\vec{b}||$, so $\ell^1$ is once again a Banach algebra under this multiplication. In this case, elements of $\ell^1$ are in 1-1 correspondence with Dirichlet series $\sum_n a_n n^{-s}$ that converge absolutely on $[0, \infty)$, and so maximal ideals of $\ell^1$ are in  1-1 correspondence with points $s \in [0, \infty)$ via $$s \mapsto \mathfrak{m}_s := \{ (a_n): \sum_{n} a_n n^{-s} = 0 \},$$ and every other ideal is an intersection of finitely many $\mathfrak{m}_s$, a power of one of the $\mathfrak{m}_s$, or some combination of the two.

> **Question 1: Is there a "canonical" way to create a Banach algebra by equipping $\ell^1$ with a permutation-invariant multiplication? If not, does every permutation-invariant Banach algebra multiplication on $\ell^1$ arise in a manner similar to the second and third examples, and can the first example also be related to this format?**
>
> **Question 2: In the Cauchy example, the maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}_1$ and $\mathfrak{m}_{-1}$ have a different structure than other maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}_x$ for $x \in (-1, 1)$, as $\mathfrak{m}_{\pm 1}^p = \mathfrak{m}_{\pm 1}$ for all integers $p > 0$, but for other values of $x$, $\mathfrak{m}_x \supsetneq \mathfrak{m}_x^2 \supsetneq \mathfrak{m}_x^3 \supsetneq...$ Something similar happens in the Dirichlet example, where $\mathfrak{m}_0^p = \mathfrak{m}_0$ for all integers $p > 0$ but for $s > 0$, $\mathfrak{m}_s \supsetneq \mathfrak{m}_s^2 \supsetneq \mathfrak{m}_s^3 \supsetneq ...$ Do these special ideals tell us anything significant about the algebra overall, and is any Banach algebra constructed from $\ell^1$ uniquely characterized by the number and nature of such special ideals?**
>
> **Question 3: How do the answers to Q1 and Q2 change for $\ell^p$ with $p > 1$? In particular, what are the corresponding answers to Q1 and Q2 for $\ell^2$ (which has an inner product) and $\ell^\infty$? Do they have a canonical permutation-invariant multiplication that turns them into a Banach algebra, and if not, can every Banach algebra over $\ell^2$ or $\ell^\infty$ be characterized by a set of special maximal ideals?**

Comment: Do you have a use in mind for the answers to these questions? I would imagine the answer to all the "is this everything?" questions is simply "no", e.g. there is no canonical multiplication, not every Banach algebra multiplication arises from some sort of convolution, etc. For one thing, you can mix multiplications, e.g. use componentwise products on the even indexes and Dirichlet convolution on the odd indexes. You could pick different convolutions for each coordinate and unify all these examples. The ideal structure questions are more interesting to me, but I have nothing insightful to say.

Comment: This was kind of a side question I thought of while pondering properties of $\Bbb{Z}[\pi]$, $\Bbb{Q}[\pi]$, and the completion $$\overline{\Bbb{Q}(\pi)} := \{ (a_n): a_n \in \Bbb{Q}, \sum_n a_n \pi^n \text{ converges absolutely} \}.$$ Let me add a condition to this question that the desired multiplication should be permutation-invariant, to avoid easy "mix-and-match" examples.

Comment: The Cauchy product and Dirichlet convolution are certainly not permutation-invariant in the sense you've added to the question.

Comment: Permutation invariant meaning norm preserving? What are two sequences that when I permute them, the norm of the Cauchy product changes?

Comment: You added some extra absolute value signs right? In any case, I agree that the Cauchy product and Dirichlet convolution are now norm-preserving in the sense of your question. It seems to be a rather strong property. The first thing that comes to mind is supposing such a product really is a convolution and coming up with a way to use e.g. products with standard basis vectors to figure out the weights in the convolution. You might get better answers if you made a new focused post on this one specific question.

Comment: Hello! For your characterization of ideals in the componentwise multiplication, I'm wondering how to prove that (if you don't require such ideal to be closed) and I've posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526705).

Comment: @WembleyInter I fixed that section to say that ideals of the componentwise multiplication are *generated by* ideals of the form specified.

Comment: @RiversMcForge Could you please elaborate on this fact that each ideal must be generated by ideals of the form specified?

Comment: @WembleyInter Every element of a proper ideal in the componentwise multiplication must have at least one component equal to zero.

Comment: I understand that, but there are proper ideals that are not contained in any of $\mathfrak{a}_I$. May I ask what is your definition of $\textit{generated by}$?

Comment: "This ideal is *generated by* that collection of ideals" means "This ideal is equal to the direct sum of the ideals in that collection": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules#Construction_for_an_arbitrary_family_of_modules 

Is that not the textbook definition of *generated by* in this specific context, or a cosmetic rephrasing thereof? I could be wrong, but I don't think I was using it in a private or idiosyncratic sense.

Comment: I can even write out an arbitrary proper ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of the ring of sequences with componentwise operations, as a direct sum $\bigoplus_{\iota \in I} \mathfrak{a}_I$ of ideals of the claimed form. If $\mathfrak{a}$ is proper, then every $a \in \mathfrak{a}$ has at least one component zero, otherwise it would be invertible and $\mathfrak{a}$ would contain the constant $1$ sequence, contradicting our assumption that $\mathfrak{a}$ is proper. Therefore $Ra$ is an ideal of the form $\mathfrak{a}_I$ as defined above, and $\mathfrak{a} = \bigoplus_{a \in \mathfrak{a}} Ra$. Boom, done.