# Help understanding this double sum in Feynman diagram cancellation rule

Tags: combinatorics, summation

In QFT we have a cancellation rule for the Feynman diagram, which involves a factorization of a double sum of the form:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \binom{n}{k} f(k)g(n-k) = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} f(k)\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} g(n)\right)
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are some generic functions.

I find this hard to prove as I am missing factors of $\frac{1}{n!(n-k)!}$.

If it's correct, how to prove it? If it's wrong, what would be the correct form?

Comment: I suspect you have not reparametrised the $(k,n)$ space correctly?

Comment: Isn't this a direct consequence of the Cauchy product for infinite series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_infinite_series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you wrote is valid. To prove it, start with equation for the [Cauchy product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202467/cauchy-product-of-two-absolutely-convergent-series-is-absolutely-convergent-ru) of two series,
$$
\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a(k)\right)\left(\sum_{h=0}^\infty b(h)\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a(k)b(n-k)
$$
which is valid for any functions $a,b:\mathbb \{0,1,2\dots\}\to \mathbb C$ for which $\sum_{k}a(k)$ and $\sum_k b(k)$ converge absolutely. Apply this equation to
$$
a(k)=(-1)^kf(k)/k!,\\
b(h)=(-1)^h g(h)/h!,
$$
to get
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k{f(k)\over k!}\right)
\left(\sum_{h=0}^\infty (-1)^h {g(h)\over h!}\right)
  &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n 
    \frac{(-1)^kf(k)}{k!}\cdot \frac{(-1)^{n-k}g(n-k)}{(n-k)!}
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n 
    (-1)^n \frac1{\color{blue}{n!}}\cdot \frac{\color{blue}{n!}}{k!(n-k)!} f(k)g(n-k)
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n 
    (-1)^n \frac1{{n!}}\cdot \binom{n}k f(k)g(n-k)
\end{align}
$$
Notice how we needed to multiply and divide by $n!$ in order to form the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}k$.